# Check checked checkbox in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
$arrayWithSelectedValues = [[user_id] => 3,[language_id] => 2], [user_id] => 3,[language_id] => 12]]
```

And I have checkbox :

```
@foreach($languages as $language)
<fieldset>
<input type="checkbox"
   class="icheckbox_square-red"
   id="input-15" name="languages[]"
   value="{{ $language->id }}">
<label for="input-15">{{ $language->name }}</label>
</fieldset>
@endforeach
```

How can I mark checkboxes as marked - those that have language_id from the array = $ language-> id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the php function in_array() to check if the $language_id exists in the array of $languages

```
@foreach($languages as $language)
<fieldset>
<input type="checkbox"
   class="icheckbox_square-red"
   id="input-15" name="languages[]"
   value="{{ $language->id }}"
   @if(in_array($language_id, $languages))
      checked
   @endif
>
<label for="input-15">{{ $language->name }}</label>
</fieldset>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$language->id` value you are looking for, and you create an array of checked language ids from `$arrayWithSelectedValues` you can do:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    @if(in_array($language->id, $languages))
       checked
    @endif
>
```

You can collected the language IDs like so:

```
$languages = [];
foreach ($arrayWithSelectedValues as $selectedValues) {
    $languages[] = $selectedValues['language_id'];
}
```

Comment: It's not working. I have array: rray:4 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 4
  2 => 3
  3 => 2
]

Comment: and checkbox: @foreach($languages as $language)
 <fieldset><input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox_square-red" id="input-15" name="languages[]"  value="{{ $language->id }}">  <label for="input-15" @if(in_array($language->id, $selectedLanguages)) checked @endif>{{ $language->name }}</label> </fieldset> @endforeach - and it's not selected :(